# How to use fscanf() to input different parameters？

Tags: c++, c

I try to use fscanf() to input parameters from txt file.
Here's my code:

```
fpin = fopen("parameter_file.txt","r");
fscanf(fpin,"%d\n", &code_value);
fscanf(fpin,"%d\n", &origin_x);
fscanf(fpin,"%d\n", &origin_y);
fscanf(fpin,"%d\n", &dpi);
fscanf(fpin,"%d\n", &width);
fscanf(fpin,"%d\n", &height);
```

And the parameter_file.txt is(for exemple):

```
333 
123 
123 
800
6
8
```

I want to add some annotation after each line. For example:
`333 //code_value` or `123 //origin_x` My problem is when I add some characters, fscanf() does not work as I desired to read the continues parameters.

I have tried `fscanf(fpin,"%[^a-z]%d\n", &code_value);`

Another problem is when the input file as follow, how can my code realize?

```
333 //code_value_1
123 //origin_x_1
123 //origin_y_1
800 //dpi_1
6 //width_1
8 //height_1
12 // code_value_2
10 //origin_x_2
20 //origin_y_2
800 //dpi_2
10 //width_2
10 //height_2
.
.
.
20 // code_value_n
10 //origin_x_n
20 //origin_y_n
800 //dpi_n
30 //width_n
30 //height_n
```

Comment: It is likely what you actually want is an XML or JSON parsing library and to make your data a bit more structured.

Comment: You need to change your format string to skip over the comments. What have you tried?

Comment: Don't use `fscanf`.  Read an entire line at a time with `getline` (if available; otherwise with `fgets`), then use `strtoul` to parse the leading number, then manually check for one or more spaces and two slashes after `endptr` before discarding the rest of the line.

Comment: Why use `fscanf` when you have marked this as C++ and C. What language are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the format is always one number per line, you can use:

```
fscanf(fpin, "%d%*[^\n]", &var);
```

The `%*[^\n]` will swallow all characters up to the newline character. The `*` is the suppression, and the `^\n` means all characters except the newline character is part of the scan set.

However, this will fail on your old style input if a newline immediately follows the number. The more robust method is to read the entire line into a buffer first, and then parse the buffer, with `sscanf()` or `strtol()`.

```
char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fpin) != 0) {
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &var) == 1) {
        /* ... */
    } else {
        /* ...handle parse error */
    }
} else {
    /* ...handle file read error */
}
```

In C++, it can be done similarly using `getline()` and an `istringstream`.

```
std::string line;
std::istringstream iss;

if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    iss.str(line);
    if (iss >> var) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...handle scan error
    }
} else {
    //...handle read error
}
```

In a comment, you ask:

> How to assign every cin to different parameter?

If each comment describes what the value represents, you can use a `map<string, int>` to create an association of names to values. Since the comments do not follow a regular format, you have to get tricky with the parsing.

The C version uses an array to store the associations. You can then later sort it (with `qsort()`) and perform binary search on it when you need to do a look up (with `bsearch()`).

```
struct value_item {
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    int value;
};

struct value_item value_map[MAX_VALUE_MAP];
size_t value_map_size = 0;

while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fpin) != 0) {
    const char *slash2 = strstr(buf, "//");
    if (slash2 && slash2[2] != '\0') {
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &value_map[value_map_size].value);
        sscanf(slash2+2, "%s", value_map[value_map_size].name);
        ++value_map_size;
    } else {
        /* ...handle parse error */
    }
}
```

The C++ version would look similar. C++ provides `map`, which you can use to easily create the association.

```
std::map<std::string, int> value_map;

while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::string::size_type n = line.find("//");
    if (n != std::string::npos && line.size() > (n+2)) {
        int value;
        std::string name;
        iss.str(line);
        iss >> value;
        iss.str(line.substr(n+2));
        iss >> name;
        value_map[name] = value;
    } else {
        //...handle parse error
    }
 }
```

I am writing this off the top of my head, so there may be errors, and nicer ways to do it. But, this should give you the general idea.

Comment: For those wondering, yes this is standard C. 7.19.6.2 for C99.

Comment: Yes. How to assign every cin to different parameter?

Comment: Was that the intention in your question? I didn't get that part out of it.

Comment: Yes. My intention is to read decimal numbers from the txt file and assign them to different parameter.

Comment: Thank you every much! I will continues work on that based on your advice!

Comment: Why will `""%d%*[^\n] "` fail?  Further, why not simple use `"%d%*[^\n]"`?  (`%d` ignores leading white space.)

Comment: @chux: `fscanf` doesn't like it when the input it is asked to scan is missing. So if there is a newline immediately after the number, `fscanf` will jam. The trailing space in the format scan string is just to get rid of the newline. No other reason.

Comment: Do not use the space at the end of the format if there's ever going to be a human driving the input.  It won't terminate until after the user hits a character that isn't white space (and usually a return too).  It works OK if the input is a file.  (The trouble is, the space reads up to the next non-blank after the newline.)  You would do much better to use `fgets()` to read the line and then use `sscanf()` to read the first number from each line.